# How do i use try_files to check for cache files

Tags: nginx

This problem is driving me crazy. I tried fixing it for at least 30mins now

if i comment out my try_files everything works correctly except my cache files are not being served (i checked via log files)

if i have the following urls

```
/
/name
/name/
```

They should match up to the files below.

```
/var/www/domain/cache/index.html
/var/www/domain/cache/name/index.html
/var/www/domain/cache/name/index.html
```

How do i use try_files to check them and if the html cache doesnt exist proceed to the rest of the location block. Here is the block in quest

```
location ~ /$ {
    #try files here
    root /var/www/domain/;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
}
```

Comment: Do you send all your requests to fastcgi/php?

Comment: @MarceloBittencourt yes but that generates the cache file and serves the html result. I want to try files so i can directly use cache when they exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
server {
     ...
     location @whatever {
        root /var/www/domain/;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        }
     location ~ /$ {
        root /var/www/domain/cache/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @whatever;
        }
}
```

Let me know if it worked...

Comment: I dont see where i specify the cache location but i tried ` location ~ /$ {
  root /path/cache;
  try_files $uri @whatever;
 }`  and putting the full location instead of using document_root. I looked at the access log an it said i tried to serve `$document_root/page` instead of `$document_root/index.php`

Comment: strange, with this incorrect configuration i can it doesnt seem to use the cache files and it reports the access of `@whatever` as `/usr/local/nginx/html`

Comment: the cache location normally is your document root... when you don't find the file you always call index.php? without adding any parameters? Can you add the access and error log messages after a request?

Comment: Sorry. i thought that you had the root value in the server context (will edit this response...)

Comment: With your edit i still dont know where to put the cache path I tried it with root being at the top but got the problem with it not checking the cache location
I played around more and i still cant figure this out. So heres the thing, i have a cache location `/path/to/app/cache/folder_aka_url/index.html;` which should fall back to `/path/to/app/index.php;`. Then regular files at `/path/to/app/$uri` and finally php files that isnt index.php also at `/path/to/app/$uri` (uri can be subfolders). I dont have root just because i have no idea how to say look-here-instead-of-root in a specific location

Comment: hum, i think i got it now... editing the answer...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1754/discussion-between-marcelo-bittencourt-and-acidzombie24)

Comment: solved via chat and this post http://kbeezie.com/view/nginx-configuration-examples/